# Query for checking if a value exists, and if it doesn't adding all rows from tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pandas

I am organizing invoices, and the invoice is one `csv` file with several thousand rows to show all the line items. Once they're imported with pandas into a temp table I need to confirm that the invoice hasn't already been added, and if it hasn't then add all of that invoices rows. Essentially:

if invoiceNumber not found in destination:
Add all rows from source
else
Add nothing

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This isn't a high priority since the code is on a set schedule and the likelihood of it trying to add duplicate invoices is next to zero, but I want to make sure all bases are covered.

Comment: You can use `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT invoiceNum FROM yourtable WHERE invoiceNum = @csvNum) BEGIN INSERT records END` This is psuedo code, but should give you all the `SQL` statements you need, you'll need to replace the column name of `invoiceNum` to whatever your column is named as well as the `@csvNum` to whatever you use to look at your csv file invoice number and then do your actual `INSERT` statement inside the `BEGIN` and `END`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this

```
INSERT Invoice....
SELECT T.* FROM Temptable T LEFT JOIN Invoice I
ON (T.InvoiceID = I.InvoiceID)
WHERE I.InvoiceID IS NULL
```

Comment: While this answer is acceptable, it does have a slight performance overhead compared to checking for a row with the csv's invoice number - (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121034/best-practice-between-using-left-join-or-not-exists)